# High noise and low voice in mic

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Hi for past few days ive been trying to figure out how to get my mic working on ubuntu first I unlocked the channels using pulse audio and set one to zero but there was still no audio turned out you cant use internal mic with a headphone connected (my headphone mic is broken).
So I used hdaJackRetask to override the mic jack after all this finally there was audio in my mic but the noise was too high and the voice felt as if it was in background.

I tried playing with mic boost in alsamixer and other settings in it but nothing proved successful if the noise was gone so was voice and if voice was there so was noise.

Please help me if there is some way to fix this background noise 
btw its static noise, even in room with 0 sound its still present.

I am on dual boot and the mic works perfectly on windows

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any workaround?
When I use microphone, it sounds like the ghost of optimus prime fighting megatron.

Comment: Check out this answer, worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio?newreg=7b860dbada2643a0b556f937282356fa