# PulseAudio doesn't load after adding noise cancellation to config

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am new to linux and want to use it as my daily driver however, I want noise cancellation for my mic and after some googling, I found out that you can edit the pulseaudio config file to load the specific module for it as shown in this :-

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Enable_Echo/Noise-Cancellation

So I opened terminal, typed

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

and then added the lines

```
 ### Enable Echo/Noise-Cancellation
load-module module-echo-cancel use_master_format=1 aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink
set-default-source echoCancel_source
set-default-sink echoCancel_sink
```

after that, I rebooted my computer but everytime I did something related to voice recording made my computer freeze for about a second (like going to Settings->Sound, starting a voice recording in Counter Strike Global Offensive, testing microphone in steam etc...).

Then I opened `pavucontrol` and saw this :-

[image: Screenshot of pavucontrol]

Does anyone have a clue as to what I am doing wrong?

Running `sudo journalctl -xe | tail -25` gives the following result :-

```
Jan 12 00:26:12 nitish-Linux obexd[2392]: OBEX daemon 5.48
Jan 12 00:26:12 nitish-Linux dbus-daemon[1390]: [session uid=1000 pid=1390] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez.obex'
Jan 12 00:26:12 nitish-Linux systemd[1185]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
-- Reboot --
Jan 11 23:54:43 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2494]: Can't cancel echo between a sink and its monitor
Jan 11 23:54:43 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2494]: Failed to load module "module-echo-cancel" (argument: "use_master_format=1 aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink"): initialization failed.
Jan 11 23:54:43 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2494]: Module load failed.
Jan 11 23:54:43 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2494]: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jan 11 23:55:15 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2515]: [pulseaudio] module-echo-cancel.c: Can't cancel echo between a sink and its monitor
Jan 11 23:55:15 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2515]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-echo-cancel" (argument: "use_master_format=1 aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink"): initialization failed.
Jan 11 23:55:15 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2515]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jan 11 23:55:15 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2515]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jan 11 23:55:15 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[2512]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Jan 12 00:10:30 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[3085]: [pulseaudio] module-echo-cancel.c: Can't cancel echo between a sink and its monitor
Jan 12 00:10:30 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[3085]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-echo-cancel" (argument: "use_master_format=1 aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=1" source_name=echoCancel_source sink_name=echoCancel_sink"): initialization failed.
Jan 12 00:10:30 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[3085]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
Jan 12 00:10:30 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[3085]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jan 12 00:10:30 nitish-Linux pulseaudio[3082]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

Comment: The set-defaults seem to be off to me, but I think you might try as recommended in [https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio)

Comment: That was actuall my first attempt after just googling "noise cancellation pulseaudio". Then I stumbled upon the wiki and gave that a shot. Also I reinstalled alsa-base and pulseaudio between the two attempts just to be sure

Comment: My confusion is from setting the source and sink to the cancellation module - I would naively think that doing one or the other (the souce) would be sufficient, but that using both may lead to a loop.

Comment: Nope, still the same issue after using just the line with source. Also typing "pulseaudio --start" in console leads to "Daemon startup failed."

Comment: Have you checked the log files for why the daemon does not start?  the `gnome-logs` program under 'applications' is a good starting point.

Comment: Have one log stating that "[pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)". Also, a few say "[pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running."

Comment: yeah, there's lots of stuff in the logs...  Try this:  In a terminal, execute `pulseaudio --kill`  then `pulseaudio --start` then `sudo journalctl -xe | tail -25`

Comment: Append the results of the journalctl command to your question (edit them in...)

Comment: Alternatively, you could run `pulseaudio -v` (adding more 'v''s if needed) to get some error messages

Comment: couldn't kill the process as it wasn't active but I did all you asked

Comment: K - I'm about out of options, although the module_echo_canced is the culprit.  I'd edit your /etc/pulse/default.pa to just `load-module module-echo-cancel`, see if it works, and then build up from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as I stated I had started my first attempt with just "load-module module-echo-cancel". All I had to do was change to hardware profile to Analog Stereo Duplex.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to it, before editing the config file, I had to make sure that the hardware for built-in Audio was configured with the profile "Analog Stereo Duplex", I had it on "Analog Stereo Output" as pointed out by :-

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sound-problems-since-last-stable-update/30773/22

> E: [pulseaudio] module-echo-cancel.c: Can’t cancel echo between a sink and its monitor
>
> Pulseaudio failed to start because module-echo-cancel couldn’t find microphone input.
>
> If only available input device is the monitor of the output sink,
>   better to have pulseaudio fail with error than try to use 2 identical
>   signals for echo cancellation. I accidentally created similar
>   situation by connecting a balanced microphone signal to a stereo line
>   - pulseaudio remixed the balanced hot and cold to mono for skype calls, all callers heard was silence because remixing the 2 out of
>   phase signals cancelled everything, but it still looked like it was
>   working in Pulseaudio Mixer.
>
> Now you have Pulseaudio started, can try to add extra module back in
>   with terminal command:
>
> ```
> pactl load-module module-echo-cancel
> ```
>
> If you still get same error, check Pulseaudio Mixer is showing device
>   is set to ‘Duplex’ to allow audio input and output, also check output
>   device is not showing as “(unplugged)”

Comment: I modified your answer to include the relevant text from the link:  AskUbuntu dislikes answers which link to other websites, as the content of those sites can change without notice.  Please be sure to come back in a day to mark your own answer as 'Accepted', and welcome to AskUbuntu!