# Echo cancellation in Ubuntu 20

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, fonts

I have added following lines to my Pulse's settings in order to have echo cancellation:

```
#Active Noise Removal
load-module module-echo-cancel
```

all works but when I turn on the machine microphone with echo cancellation hides. When I delete the two lines, restart the machine and add once more time all works fine..

How to make it working at bootstrap as expected, any ideas? The same situation is with the fonts in top bar, when I increase all works but after restart I have default *smaller* fonts. The system was upgraded from 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 20 sucks heavily on this (as many other things). The only working solution I found was to

1. Create a startup script with line:

```
sleep 60s && pactl load-module module-echo-cancel
```

Script could be run by **Startup Application Preferences**.

Explanation:

- `sleep 60s` - we need to wait until pulseaudio is ready, it's shorter time but I didn't care, 60 seconds is ok for me

2. Put some configuration in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink
set-default-source noechosource
set-default-sink noechosink
```

3. Set in `/etc/pulse/client.conf`

```
default-source = noechosource
```

This is all.

---

This is hideous solution, but I couldn't find anything better.

Other solutions found on the web didn't work, like:

- [PulseAudio doesn't load after adding noise cancellation to config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108925/pulseaudio-doesnt-load-after-adding-noise-cancellation-to-config)
- https://www.informaticar.net/enable-noise-cancellation-in-ubuntu/
- https://medium.com/@rahul.y.dudhane/how-to-do-noise-and-echo-cancellation-in-ubuntu-7a5607c7e887

Comment: Thanks, do you have "sucks list" of Ubuntu 20?

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk No, I don't have one... but it's something strange in Ubuntu, that they are keeping "desktop-linux community" alive, but at the same time they are choosing "strange" paths. Previously was slow Unity environment, now it's fast Gnome, but difficult to configure, and snap doesn't have good opinions either. I was quite unhappy with linux mint because of old packages, but now I'm quite unhappy because of the system. There is no place to go in Linux world.