# Realtime audio preprocessing with buffering

Tags: sound, microphone

- Assume that my microphone audio is being live streamed to a Zoom app
  (could be any application in general)
- I want to run this audio through an executable (a `filter`) before
  being sent to the application.  Naively, this piping mechanism: `raw input | filter | application`.
- I need to maintain a buffer in my `filter`, assume around 50ms
  (because the audio preprocessing is dynamic), and *only* then *flush* that
  to the application, like how I/O works in general.
- Let's say I am coding this in C++ (although Python would be
  preferred, since a bit of ML is involved in the audio preprocessing).

(In effect, the application would be receiving a 50ms delayed audio from my end, but practically this does not matter for me.)

How to achieve this? Since this is quite a broad field, I want to specifically know a way to do the following:

1. capture raw audio data (from - assume - a headset)
2. process the raw audio buffer using a C++ executable (preferably Python, though) which maintains it in a 50ms buffer, and then
3. flushes the post-processed buffer to a live stream application (like Zoom, etc.)

I have seen the [noise removal with pulseaudio post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio) post, but my desired audio processing is much more general than just using a built-in pulseaudio module or profiling noise using sox.

Comment: Have you looked into OBS studio? It's designed for broadcasting

Comment: @Nmath Hi, I am not so sure OBS is the right tool for this, but I'll have a look.

Comment: You could have a look at [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/).