# Noise from mic recording audio with screen recording

Tags: sound, microphone, noise, kazam

I want to make a video tutorial.During recording,I am getting heavy noise(video link attached) from mic,probably it is recording laptop internal fan noise.But,there is no noise from mic in zoom or other video calling software.I have tried  kazam,ssr, vokoscreen.Is there any fix?

Or can I record audio from external headphone mic.[Mic sound noise video](https://youtu.be/gVeRYhmVa-0)

Comment: Did you adjust (decrease) the audio input levels for your mic beforehand? If not, re-record the first minute of your recording in order to make a comparison. Also make sure that your mic doesn't pick up on electrostatic noise, generated by other electronics. Same goes for vibrations (computer fan). Generated noise in recordings can also be filtered out afterwards. Audacity offers an option for recording and also for different noise reduction/canceling filters (consult youtube tutorials).

Comment: I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/765024/1649110) should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using a headset with built-in microphone with Ubuntu LTS 20.04.1. Similar to you, I get lots of background noise in my microphone input. I get complaints when I speak on Zoom due to my workstation's fans being active. Unfortunately, I have not found a good way of eliminating the background noise automatically through Ubuntu. The  best option is to record in a quiet setting. That may mean moving noisy items farther away. Also, if you can find a microphone that has noise elimination features built in, that would be a great choice too. It should be possible to eliminate noise in the microphone hardware so the input has less noise other than your voice.