# Alternative way to suppress the noise in microsoft teams

Tags: 18.04, microphone, noise, zoom-meeting, microsoft-teams

When our mic is turned on in a Teams meeting or call, background noise around we—shuffling papers, slamming doors, barking dogs, and so on—can distract others. We need to suppress this noise. [Right now, This sound suppressing is only supported for windows desktop and we dont have support for ubuntu](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-background-noise-in-teams-meetings-1a9c6819-137d-4b3b-a1c8-4ab20b234c0d)

Is there any alternative way to suppress the background noise?

Comment: It's annoying that the linux client lags so much behind.  We follow meeting etiquette and mute our mike until we speak :(.

Comment: Use OBS as input and configure OBS to cancel noise.

Answer (score 5):

I have one way to do it.
You can install pulse audio in your ubuntu using  the command

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

In [pulse audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) you can do real time noise cancellation.
Here is how to setup pulse audio for noise cancellation => [Realtime noise-removal with PulseAudio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio)

Edit: Found another way, It works very well. [NoiceTorch](https://github.com/lawl/NoiseTorch) - Real-time microphone noise suppression on Linux.

Comment: NoiseTorch has been declared dead in it's read me file.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hypothesis. Install a Windows VM inside of VirtualBox and Microsoft Teams in there to see if their virtualization of hardware such as sound controls your problem effectively.

Comment: will check this

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve very good results with Cadmus - https://github.com/josh-richardson/cadmus. This integrates nicely with GNOME eg. and is quite easy to use.

Comment: will check this