# Muted microphone ubuntu

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I was trying to enable noise cancellation on ubuntu 20.04 LTS and was able to do it from  [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1323781/1545483). Then I was trying to fix echo from local speakers and followed [this tutorial](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-turn-off-audio-echo-from-microphone-to-local-speakers/) and I was no longer able to get sound from the microphone, anyone can please help me and also enable noise cancellation and also fix echo from local speakers ? thanks in advanced !!

Comment: A 10 years old tutorial is hardly relevant due to the huge changes any OS experiences in such long period of time. That said the second guide you followed simply calls for changing the audio card output. It should be easily reversible.

Comment: got it, thanks alot when i changed the input I was able to get audio back!! but still there is alot of echo from my local speakers but other than that noise cancelling is really good...