Ubuntu 24 pipewire karaoke setup
I first set out to make my sennheiser XS 1 (with just XLR to jack cable, no amp or external sound card) not sound like total ass and this guide I found here really did the job in my view: https://askubuntu.com/a/1464845/307184
it's a good step-by-step and has the added benefit of configuring things in your .config folder, the ubuntu way.
(note that the step by step doesn't say this but there is a final couple steps: selecting your new "Noise Cancelling Source" from the list of inputs in your sound settings and closing and reopening any apps that use inputs and or outputs (so that they switch to the new sources, spotify for example needs a restart to play music once again)
Now I want to create a playback of the singing into the microphone. What I'm struggling with here is that if I just add :
{   name = libpipewire-module-loopback }

into my input-filter-chain.conf
then it sorta works but sounds like a really low quality karaoke. you hear yourself but it's mostly echo and since it's mostly echo it also sounds slightly delayed.
it's functional but really subpar.
I also tried a more in-depth version :
{   name = libpipewire-module-loopback
    args = {
        node.description = "Loopback"
        capture.props = {
            audio.position = [ FL ]
            stream.dont-remix = true
            node.target = "rnnoise_source"
            node.passive = true
        }
        playback.props = {
            node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
            media.class = "Audio/Source"
            audio.position = [ MONO ]
        }
    }
}
{   name = libpipewire-module-echo-cancel
  args = {
      # library.name  = aec/libspa-aec-webrtc
      # node.latency = 1024/48000
      source.props = {
         node.name = "Echo Cancellation Source"
      }
      sink.props = {
         node.name = "Echo Cancellation Sink"
      }
      }
}

same result.
I'm trying to create the premium experience here.
I've also tested activating playback outside of pipewire: like for example enabling audio monitoring on record in Audacity but this has the exact same echo-y result.
this basically means that in all cases I tried where I play the mic out into the speaker the mic is hearing itself in the speaker.
Is what I want to do impossible?
